# Autofac RegisterGeneric aggregate generic type

Tags: entity-framework, generics, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

I have 3 projects, core project with interfaces and two implementations who use a specific EntityFramework DbContext each.
And I want to have a Generic repository and register which context to use in the container builder of each project.

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T item);
    T Find(object id);
    IEnumerable<T> List();
}

public class PostgresqlRepository<T,K> : IRepository<T> where T : class
        where K : DbContext,new()
{
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        using (var db = new K())
        {
            db.Set<T>().Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public T Find(object id)
    {
        using (var db = new K())
        {
            return db.Set<T>().Find(id);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> List()
    {
        using (var db = new K())
        {
            return db.Set<T>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to register in each project the context to use(K) e.g.:
`builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(PostgresqlRepository<,>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>));`

Where can I indicate the typeof(K) class?

How can I do this?